# Nhibernate row number over partition c#

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, row-number

I an new in nhibernate and need your help.

How can I  execute this sql query in nhibernate-criteria C#

```
select * from
(
 select *, row_number() over (partition by questionaireId order by stepnumber desc) rid
 from myTable 
) t
where t.rid=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, small note: `Select *` won't work, all columns must be named explicitly. Secondly I am not sure what are you trying to achieve. If this should do some kind of paging I have better suggestion **(*number 2) below*)**. But let's try to do what you want first.

**1)** So, taken into account, that we should select column explicitly, here is a way how to transform your SQL statement into Criteria syntax:

```
var list = session
  .CreateCriteria<MyEntity>() // mapped to 'myTable' table 
  .SetProjection
  (
       Projections.SqlProjection
       (        
          "Code, Name, row_number() over (partition by questionaireId order by stepnumber desc) as rid"
          , new string[] {"Code", "Name"}
          , new IType[] { NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.String
                     , NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.String }
       )
  )
  .SetMaxResults(1)  // this is something like t.rid = 1
  .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<MyEntity>())
  .List<MyEntity>()
;
```

If your mapped class `MyEntity` has properties `Code` and `Name`... this will execute select like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Code, Name
 , row_number() over (partition by questionaireId order by stepnumber desc) rid
 FROM myTable
```

and when executed, the result is bounded into properties (Code, Name) and only first row ordered by your clause is selected.

**2) Native NHibernate paging**

Because you've mentioned: *I am new in NHibernate* I am guessing that you are trying to get paging based on Order By property. If this is the case, your solution is much more simple. use this Criteria:

```
var list = session
  .CreateCriteria<MyEntity>()
  .AddOrder(new Order("stepnumber", false)) // the property to be used for ORDER BY
  .Add(... where conditions ala ICriterion
  ...
  .SetFirstResult(100)                      // skip 100 rows
  .SetMaxResults(20)                        // take 20 rows
  .List<Country>();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't make partitions. However, you could create your query in a view, and execute that view from NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Named queries might be useful, see the NHibernate reference.